# I get this error when import framer-motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

When I import framer-motion like this:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
```

This error occurs:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

How do I fix this? I installed `framer-motion`, and it was working fine in other projects.

Comment: It seems that the error is not related to the import

Answer (score 1):

I just reinstalled framer motion and everything worked.

```
npm uninstall framer-motion

npm i framer-motion
```